# Owin Nancy Fx. Hookup to request events. BeforeRequest, AfterRequest, OnError

Tags: .net, owin, nancy

I need to configure Nhibernate for a web app using Nancy and Owin and want to inject and open a session instance on request, close it after the request and rollback on error.

using just Nancy I would have done something like this:

```
this.ApplicationPipelines.BeforeRequest += BeforeRequest;
this.ApplicationPipelines.AfterRequest += AfterRequest;
this.ApplicationPipelines.OnError += OnError;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used NancyFX, but I think what you want is something as follows (using Katana)

```
class RequestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public RequestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        // Do stuff before passing on the request
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        // Do stuff after request/on response
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 500)
        {
            // Server had an error
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a middleware to watch incoming/outgoing requests and do stuff based on the request or response. You'll have to manage 'catching' the errors yourself.